# How to Play HTTPS Secured Audio Stream with Basic Authentication by using HTML5 Audio Player

Tags: windows, html, https, html5-audio, basic-authentication

I am using HTML5 Audio Player to play secured audio stream which requires basic authentication. When I click on play button media player gets disappear automatically.

But when I copy the URL and paste that in new tab, it asks for credentials and then start playing it on browser. So, when I play recording (with basic authentication) on browser just once, HTML5 audio mediaplayer also start playing recording (as credentials are saved on browser now).

```html
<audio id="{{call.id}}" ng-src="{{audio_src}}" controls autoplay>
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

And this the sample URL to access Media File to play:

```
https://username:password@192.168.1.1:1234/recordedMedia/oramedia/mp4/2b152495b72811.mp4
```

I am using Mozilla Firefox, Do I need to make any configurational change in my browser setting or any other workaround?